# Series.Expanding within Group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to find the series expanding rank within each category in a group by.

Current formula returns the expanding rank across the whole series in the data frame. I want the expanding window to reset at each category.

| Category | Value | Current Output Rank | Expected Output: Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 1 (Smallest in [10]) | 1 (Smallest in [10]) |
| A | 20 | 2 (Second Smallest in [10,20]) | 2 (Second smallest in [10,20]) |
| A | 30 | 3 (Third Smallest in [10,20,30]) | 3 (Third smallest in [10.20,30]) |
| B | 40 | 4 (Fourth Smallest in [10,20,30,40]) | 1 (Smallest in [40]) |
| B | 50 | 5 (Fifth Smallest in [10,20,30,40,50]) | 2 (Smallest in [40,50]) |
| C | 60 | 6 (Sixth Smallest in [10,20,30,40,50,60]) | 1 (Smallest in [60]) |

I tried the following

```
df['rank']=df.groupby(['Category'])['value'].transform(lambda x: df['Value'].expanding(1).rank(ascending=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Category' : list('AAABBC'), 'Value' : range(10, 70, 10)})
```

`df`

```
Category    Value
0   A       10
1   A       20
2   A       30
3   B       40
4   B       50
5   C       60
```

**Code**

```
df.assign(Rank=df.groupby('Category').expanding()['Value'].rank().droplevel(0))
```

output:

```
Category    Value   Rank
0   A       10      1.0
1   A       20      2.0
2   A       30      3.0
3   B       40      1.0
4   B       50      2.0
5   C       60      1.0
```

**intermediate**

```
df.groupby('Category').expanding()['Value'].rank()
```

intermediate:

```
Category   
A         0    1.0
          1    2.0
          2    3.0
B         3    1.0
          4    2.0
C         5    1.0
```

Comment: This seems to work, thanks!

df.assign(Rank=df.groupby('Category').expanding()['Value'].rank().droplevel(0))

I'm a bit new to pandas, why do you use the drop level over transform?

Comment: This is to make the index of intermediate and `df`  same. The reason to make it the same is to make it column